# SuiteCRM, GCP and Maria DB - too much?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mariadb, bitnami, suitecrm

Okay,

So we have MariaDB on the backend, all configured and set up. VPC peering with GCP and a VM that uses Bitnamia Lauchpad for GCP to launch SuiteCRM.

I can access our SuiteCRM page, can see our MariaDB tables and such, but I can't find the SuiteCRM config files to change the database connection to point to the MariaDB database instance.

What am I missing here? I've dug around through GCP and the Bitnami admin screens, best I can find is the SSH read option of the files but no way to change them. I've seen a few site that have similar walk throughs, but end up using AWS or some other piece so no real information.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here, if you want to access the SuiteCRM files and edit the configuration, you will need to SSH the app's instance ([using the in-browser SSH tool or any SSH tool in your computer](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/get-started/connect-ssh/)) and modify the configuration files under /opt/bitnami/suitecrm.

Comment: Hello Jota, thank you for the response! So it turns out that the initial issues I had were related to some set up issue on MariaDB's side. Still having issues, thinking it's related to the pem file and such. I have it uploaded to the /opt/bitnami/suitecrm folder and referenced in the config but still running into a "cannot access the database" error on load. Been digging around the last couple of days and coming up short on ideas. Do I push back to the MariaDB support?

Comment: If you didn't modify the app's configuration, it should use the pre-defined user/password we configure during the installation. Can you confirm the database is started (`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start mariadb`)and that you can use using the root user and the password we configure for you?

Comment: So after initial launch from launch pad, SuiteCRM does work fine. It's getting it configured to use the MariaDB instance. Config file has been changed to point to the host, user, password, port. DBconfigOptions set to use SSL as true and pathed to the pem file. Still getting an error of cannot connect to the database though.

Comment: `Config file has been changed to point to the host, user, password, port.`. So you are using another database server, right? In that case, please confirm you can access that database remotely by using the client: `mysql -u USER -p -h HOST -P PORT`

Comment: Well I was able to run the above command including the -i for the pem file the other day and it connected.. now it's again showing unable to connect.

Comment: I got it!! There was a typo it looks like in the MysqliManager.php file that was sent to me from the Maria tech.. We're up and running now!

Comment: Perfect! I'm glad to hear that :)